# Mensaje de gitbash al hacer un merge al main

Tags: git, github, git-bash, ramas-git

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gitbash me tira esta ventana cuando hago el merge: `git merge Diego2`

Comment: Que problema tienes? Puedes ponerle un mensaje o no...

Comment: pues escribo y doy enter pero nada

Comment: Ok. Estás en un editor tipo VIM. Te recomiendo que busques información sobre este editor. En tu caso, para guardar y salir debes pulsar `ESC, luego escribir :wq y enter`. Es la secuencia típica para guardar y salir en ese editor

Comment: como escribo cuando salgo?

Comment: yo doy esacpe y al rpesionar wq me pone como @listening q

Comment: Has pulsado el : antes del wq?

Comment: ah no xd, pense que era para msotra qu te nia que ahcer